# Запись/чтение файла Guitar Pro (*.gtp) с помощью c#

Tags: c#

Может какую-нибудь либу посоветуете.. или просто принцип работы с такими файлами

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878012/reading-guitar-pro-files

Comment: @maxwell хороший линк. Может возьметесь перевести кратко ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вольный перевод и компиляция из ответов [с en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878012/reading-guitar-pro-files) по ссылке, предложенной в комментариях @maxwell.

Есть приложение на Java c открытым исходным кодом -- [TuxGuitar](http://tuxguitar.herac.com.ar/), можете посмотреть его исходники.

Также есть [описание формата GTP](http://dguitar.sourceforge.net/GP4format.html), полученное реверс-инжинирингом. Также можно посмотреть исходники самого DGuitar, который представляет из себя проигрыватель gtp (*.GP4,*.GP3,GTP). Правда, для этого нужно понимать Java, так как этот проигрыватель написан на нём.

Также можно посмотреть исходники [kguitar](http://kguitar.sourceforge.net/), это также проигрыватель gtp но на c++ и qt.

На c# есть [приложение](http://phoneguitartab.codeplex.com/) просмотрщик gtp для Windows Phone ([переехало на git](https://github.com/reinterpretcat/phoneguitartab))